# Is it possible to use glScalef on a bitmap that is drawn with glBitmap?

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat, freetype2, opengl-1.x

I'm making a text renderer that uses FreeType 2 and legacy OpenGL. Problem is, FreeType 2's coordinate system has (0, 0) in the top left corner while OpenGL's coordinate system is Cartesian. This means I have to flip the bitmap. I expected glScalef to work with glBitmap but it has no effect. Can anyone tell me if it's possible to flip a bitmap vertically with glScalef, or if it is not possible, point me to some other source that can flip a bitmap upside down (Preferably efficiently as possible)?

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
glBitmap(size_x, size_y, 0, 0, xadd, yadd, (GLubyte *) bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `glPixelZoom`.

> Pixel zoom factors are not limited to positive values. Negative zoom factors reflect the resulting image about the current raster position.

It definitely will have the desired effect on `glDrawPixels`.  There's a note in `glBitmap` saying that it acts like `glDrawPixels` but I cannot find any explicit statement on whether `glPixelZoom` applies to `glBitmap` or not, so YMMV.

Comment: I tested it and nothing happened... does it work with glBitmap or only glDrawPixels? I've heard that glDrawPixels is pretty inefficient and would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: `glBitmap` said "The bitmap image is interpreted like image data for the glDrawPixels command, with width and height corresponding to the width and height arguments of that command, and with type set to GL_BITMAP and format set to GL_COLOR_INDEX. Modes specified using glPixelStore affect the interpretation of bitmap image data; modes specified using glPixelTransfer do not." so I was hoping that it indeed meant it was treated like glDrawPixels data.

Comment: If by `glDrawPixels` you are referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777965/103167 then yes he's right, and the same caution applies to `glBitmap`.  Textures are just better although more complicated to set up.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go figure out how to use textures since they seem to be more flexible than ```glBitmap```.